# Post a msg to fb from my app using official facebook app installed in phone

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a listview of 15 items . Each icon is for a social media . One icon is for facebook . On small click , user will be directed to installed facebook app of facebook . In long click , a dialog box like the following will be opened .

[image]

After clicking post button I want to post this status via facebook apps installed in my phone . I have no idea how to implement this . Please help me . Any suggestions will help me a lot .

Comment: This may helpful to you complete information about Facebook integration in android: [Go to this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

Comment: Do you know about facebook developer ? if not then just search in Google.